When did Rome take the power of capital punishment away from the Jews?
The septre of Judah was not taken away "until Shiloh come". My contention would be that, as I read it, when Jesus was born, the power was taken.
Here's the reference:

The scepter shall not depart from Judah, nor the ruler's staff from
between his feet, until [tribute comes to him OR until he comes to
whom it belongs OR until he comes to Shiloh]; and to him shall be the
obedience of the peoples. – Genesis 49:10 ESV


Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! The purpose of the site is to analyze biblical scripture, which you allude to but have not cited. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

@Edward Young please add a biblical reference.   (John 18:31)

Welcome to the BH forum, @Edward Young. I took the liberty of adding the scripture reference to your question to make it conform to BH courtesy. Best wishes.

Thank you for the reference addition. The answers are very well thought out and thorough. It seems the question cannot be conclusively answered. I believe the scripture is saying it was so, but I was still hoping for that bit of archeological confirmation. Thank you Dan and Dieter!

If Rome did forbid the Jewish leadership to exercise capital punishment, it's interesting that the council et al had no problem stoning Stephen to death in Acts 7.

The Greek Septuagint, a translation of the Old Testament (aka the Tanakh) from the third century BC (or BCE) reads as follows:

A ruler shall not fail from Judah, and the one leading from his
thighs, until whenever should come the things reserved to him; and
the expectation of the nations [ethnos in Greek, SG1484, which can mean the gentiles]. – Genesis 49:10 ABP

According to the Jewish Virtual Library

Ten years after Herod's death (4 BCE), Judea came under direct Roman
administration.
https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/roman-rule-63bce-313ce

Jesus was born in the tiny village of Bethlehem, let's assume just before the death of Herod in 4 BC. Thus, around 7 AD (or 7 CE), Jesus would have been 11-12 years old when he appeared before the Torah teachers in Jerusalem (see Luke 2:41-47).
Speculation Trigger Warning (STW): Maybe there was something like a Bar Mitzvah recognition back in the first century or before . . .
This set of interpretations then fulfills the prophecy in Genesis 49 and answers your question about when the Judeans lost the right of capital punishment mentioned in John 18:31.
Naturally, all of these dates are controversial as are all of the scriptures.
Hope this helps.

The sources are not entirely clear on the OP's headline question. The idea comes from John 18:31b, in which Jewish religious leaders state: “We do not have the right to execute anyone." Ellicott states that the policy was instituted after Archelaus was deposed and Judæa became a Roman province (A.D. 6 or 7). Several others put the date at "forty years before the destruction of Jerusalem." But a note in the New American Bible Revised Edition says:

Only John gives this reason for their bringing Jesus to Pilate. Jewish
sources are not clear on the competence of the Sanhedrin at this
period to sentence and to execute for political crimes.

The NT informs us that both Herod I and his son Herod Antipas put people to death. Herod I was infamous for putting large numbers of people to death according to Josephus, and the Gospel of Matthew reports that he also killed many very young boys in order to prevent the messiah from surviving. Antipas was the Herod who beheaded John the Baptist. However, there is no indication that there was any trial under Jewish law in these cases. The case of the stoning of Stephen (Acts 5) likewise does not mention a trial, nor does the story of the intended stoning of the woman taken in adultery. (John 8:7)
Presuming that the statement of "the Jews" in John 18 is correct, the Romans seem to have instituted this rule around the time that Pontius Pilate became procurator. Since Antipas (who reigned in the northern areas of Israel) executed John the Baptist with a year or two of Jesus' death,  the policy may have been a local limitation placed by Pilate on the Sanhedrin in Jerusalem.
Regarding the meaning of "when Shiloh comes," the scepter had been taken from Judah's tribe long before this, when the Babylonians defeated the nation of Judah. When the kingdom of Judea was restored after the Maccabean Revolt, those kings were Levites, and not from the tribe of Judah. Under Roman rule, King Herod was an Idumean (Edomite). So the scepter had been permanently taken from Judah long before this.
Conclusion: It is not absolutely certain that the power of execution was taken from the Jews. If the report in John 18 is correct, it seems that this was a local policy instituted under Pontius Pilate.
